# Can one use a trained recurrent neural network to find the most probable sequence of a set?

Tags: recurrent-neural-networks

Let's say I train an RNN on the sequence of characters in *War and Peace*. After doing so is there a way I can take an arbitrary set of letters, e.g. HNTASK, and have it (ideally) tell me that the most probable sequence of that set is THANKS?

Also the algorithm must use ONLY the characters in that set; i.e. I don't want it to guess that *U* comes after *H*, even if *U* appeared in the training examples. After each character it can only pick from remaining ones. I would assume one would somehow disable the illegal output neurons to do this.

(I know there are far simpler algorithms for transforming jumbled-up letters to English words. This is just a toy example for an important problem.)